# Android webView external link -> new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, hyperlink, external

In activity 1 I got a web view. For each link to a external website (e.g. if you are on facebook and you click a link to amazon) should activity 2 be started.

Activity 2 contains also a web view. This web view should load the clicked link from activity 1.

I read about the "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" method. But the new one is provided in a too high api level. And the deprecated one triggers for each click in the web view (also if you dont leave the site). I could filter - but it's still deprecated.

So I tried this way:

```
 WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

                view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                    @Override public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean dialog, boolean userGesture, Message resultMsg)
                    {
                        Intent externalLinkIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExternalLinkActivity.class);
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("externalLink", "externalLinkGoesHere");
                        externalLinkIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(externalLinkIntent);

                        return true;
                    }

                });
```

This method triggers only if I really LEAVE the actual site. But for me it is not possible to get out the damn url of the resultMsg. Normally it is used to call the default chrome browser for external links.

Are there any ideas or other ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SOLVED

```
public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
    String targetUrl = view.getHitTestResult().getExtra();
    //More actions
}
```

Comment: It may not be that simple. This should work for many cases, but it will not work for "JavaScript links". Check this documentation: "If the anchor does not have a URL or if it is a JavaScript URL, the type will be UNKNOWN_TYPE and the URL has to be retrieved through requestFocusNodeHref(Message) asynchronously"  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#getHitTestResult()

Comment: Furthermore, even if you get the URL successfully, it may not be sufficient for opening the new window correctly, depending on the use case. The original and the new window may need to exchange messages (the same way browser tabs can communicate with each other). In that case it seems you have to use the recommended approach of `resultMessage.obj.setWebView(newWebView); resultMessage.sendToTarget();` and open the new webview in the same activity as the original webview.

Comment: `view.getHitTestResult().getExtra();` return `null` not more that.